# Regex for textChanged event of TextBox

Tags: c#, .net, regex, winforms

In my project, There are many `TextBoxes` inside `TabControl` to which I am giving same event something like this: (*working*)

In my form constructor:

```
    SetProperty(this);
```

---

```
private void SetProperty(Control ctr)
{
    foreach (Control control in ctr.Controls)
    {
        if (control is TextBox)  
        {
            control.TextChanged += new EventHandler(ValidateText);
        }
        else
        {
           if (control.HasChildren) 
           {
               SetProperty(control);  //Recursive function if the control is nested
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to give TextChanged event to all the TextBoxes. something like this:

```
    private void ValidateText(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
        String strpattern = @"^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\'\' ']{1,20}$"; //Pattern is Ok
        Regex regex = new Regex(strpattern);  
        //What should I write here?             
    }
```

I dont know what to write in the above method because there is not one textbox to consider. Please suggest.

EDIT: The pattern I mentioned shouldn't be allowed into the TextBoxes i.e the Text should be converted in to matching string  automatically. (should disallow the characters I mentioned in the pattern).

Comment: Are you worried that different textboxes will have different validation patters?

Comment: nope.. Here I am trying to give same validation patterns to all which I dont know how to do..

Answer (score 3):

You should first grab the reference of the calling `TextBox` and then you can match the *regular expression* for validation to take any decision you want.

```
private void ValidateText(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txtBox = sender as TextBox;
    String strpattern = @"^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\'\' ']{1,20}$"; //Pattern is Ok
    Regex regex = new Regex(strpattern);
    if (!regex.Match(txtBox.Text).Success)
    {
        // passed
    }
}
```

**ADDED**, Better is to hook `Validating` event, you can call this event anytime you wish to perform Validation for all the `TextBoxes` at once.

```
private void SetProperty(Control ctr)
{
    foreach (Control control in ctr.Controls)
    {
        if (control is TextBox)
        {
            control.Validating += ValidateText;
        }
        else
        {
            if (control.HasChildren)
            {
                SetProperty(control);  //Recursive function if the control is nested
            }
        }
    }
}

private void ValidateText(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txtBox = sender as TextBox;
    String strpattern = @"^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\'\' ']{1,20}$"; //Pattern is Ok
    Regex regex = new Regex(strpattern);
    //What should I write here?
    if (!regex.Match(txtBox.Text).Success)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
    e.Cancel = false;
}
```

To perform the validation, call this method:

```
bool isValid = !this.ValidateChildren(ValidationConstraints.Enabled);
```

References:

1. [Extend the Textbox Control to Validate Against Regular Expressions](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17423/Extend-the-Textbox-Control-to-Validate-Against-Reg)
2. [Validation in Windows Forms](http://blog.scosby.com/post/2010/02/11/Validation-in-Windows-Forms.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for response.. The pattern I provided should not be allowed in to the textbox.. how to do that?

Comment: Add a `not` (`!`) before `Regex.Match`?

Comment: Guess, the validation will happen if you set the `CausesValidation` property.

Comment: no.. that means that my range of text length is between 1 to 20 only.

Comment: In the top comment, you said "The pattern I provided should not be allowed in to the textbox"???

Comment: Yea now it seems the pattern should be allowed in the textbox.

Comment: allowing or disallowing differs simply by `!` that doesn't matter. The problem now I am facing is that it is allowing all the characters including the pattern provided as well as out of pattern too.

Comment: You cannot just disallow while user is keying in because the input cannot be compared with the pattern until it is complete. After that validation can takes place and then if the match results in the failure you can simply empty that textbox. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

you also can send textbox control say this.textbox1 to the event handler method and check the input text of that control with regular expression inside the event handler.